# Using CSV node module in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension for chrome and one of the needed functionality is to make it possible to save user's data locally (But I do plan to integrate Gdrive saving). I wanted to save user's data into CSV assuming that it would be easier but it turned out a disaster.

I have tried many different methods in order to make it possible but it seems like it's no use.

Here's part of the code that doesn't work:

```
    var { parse } = require('csv-parse');

    const fs = require("chrome-fs");
    const records = [];

    const csvFile = chrome.runtime.getURL("save_file.csv");

    var parser = parse({ columns: true }, function(err, records) {
        console.log(records);
    });

    fs.createReadStream(chrome.runtime.getURL("save_file.csv")).pipe(parser);
```

and here's an error that browser throws at me when I try to initialize this code:

```
Uncaught Error
    at chrome.js:511:1
```

```
    if (err.name === 'NotFoundError') {
            var enoent = new Error()
511:        enoent.code = 'ENOENT'
            callback(enoent)
```

Comment: You've compiled this code, correct? You're not just trying to run something with `require` directly in the browser?

Comment: You [may want to look at this documentation](https://csv.js.org/parse/distributions/browser_esm/#webpack-module-bundler).

Comment: @Samathingamajig I mean, I code in VS Code and I compile it with the command `npm run watch` and am using webpack for that. also al libraries have been installed with npm so they all are there.

Comment: @Andy I looked into it and added needed configurations and also changed path, but it's no use. It throws the same error at me. It's some kind of error from ` window.requestFileSystem(`  

and the line it points to is
 
`if (err.name === 'NotFoundError') { var enoent = new Error(); enoent.code = 'ENOENT'; callback(enoent)}` 

I added into webpack's config this:

`output: {filename: 'parse.js',path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),}`

Comment: I also use chrome-extension-CLI module that includes webpack and creates the 'base' for the project to make your code in and then build it all together.

Comment: Could it be because browsers don't allow for browser extensions to use `fs` or any other way of interacting with files? even if this file literally located and downloaded with extension?